# Происхождение слова "портной"

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Прочитал вопрос о **зашиваться** и задумался над происхождением слова **портной**.
Первое предположение, которое пришло в голову, — это тот, кто шьет порты (штаны).
Но тут же приходит следующий вопрос: а откуда взялось слово **порты**? От слова "пороть" (в смысле "распарывать").
И тут же еще один вопрос: какая связь между словом **пороть** (в смысле распарывать ткань) и **пороть** (в смысле "бить")?
Вот такая цепочка вопросов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Словарь Успенского: 
  "Слово "порт" в народном языке в наши дни означает, как отмечает В. Даль,
пеньковую и льняную пряжу, холст. "Сукно с портом" - с льняной ниткой
в основе. В древнерусском языке "портъ" означало, по-видимому, всякую материю
и одежду. "Портной" - мастер по пошиву "порта", платья."
    Портки - явно от того же корня.
    Пороть в смысле бить. Пороли розгами, ремнем и т.п., то есть предметами, оставлявшими рубцы на коже сразу же во время наказания. Кожу как бы "распарывали". Имхо

Answer (score 4):

Портной – от пъртный шьвьцо, где пъртъ – одежда. С 16 века отмечено употребление  сочетания "портной мастер", а с 18 века его уже заменяет существительное  "портной" (в словарях с 1762 года).

Родственными словами являются портки и портянки. Также существовало слово "портно" - пеньковая, посконная или льняная грубая пряжа, либо холст, от которого и произошло слово "пъртъ (одежда).

Итак, порт – это льняное полотно, ОТРЕЗОК грубой ткани.  Возможно, оно связано с глаголами пороть/пырять, сравнить (греч.)  piero – колю, режу.

Значение глагола «пороть»  (наказывать) сходно с  глаголом «сечь».

Answer (score 0):

Портол - одежда (даргинское слово)

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вникнуть в смысл штанов и портов. Нужны ли были жителям Срединоземноморья штаны и порты? Им достаточно было легких туник для прикрытия срама. Иное дело у северян. Им нужна была защита ног и тела от холодов и от травмирования; каково им было пробираться сквозь дебри, да болота. Конечно первейшей защитой служили шкуры окружающих животных. Обрезанную кремнем по размеру
 шкуру скрепляли сквозь пробитые костью дырки прутьями. Резкими толчками, пыром. Прут и пыр - вот два слова могущие быть в основе древнеславянского пъртъ. Со временем пъртъ превратилось в порт - защиту ноги, а соединенные на поясе веревочкой - в порты. Присоединенные к широкому кожаному поясу, а пояс опоясывал стан, образовали конструкцию, названную станы. Записанные с помощью латиницы как stani могли произноситься немцами как штаны.  В истории становления письменности - явление обычное. Через многие сотни лет, когда изобрели ткацкий станок, портки стали шить. Итак, порты - это устройство (место) ,  предназначенное для защиты от негативного воздействия окружающей среды. Кто возразит? Возникло и использовалось в местах проживания славян. А теперь предлагаю подумать и представить себе как слово порт проникло в название греческих портиков, в название Португалии, в название пристанища кораблей.

Comment: какая каша...

Comment: Ну так, для справки: В банях и общественных термах не было обычным ношение специальной одежды. Уличную одежду оставляли у входа в раздевалке и оставались лишь в тунике, если собирались играть в мяч или другие игры. Купались обычно раздетыми. Лишь немногие римляне надевали в бани набедренные повязки[27]. Так же римлянам были известны своего рода «бикини», как видно на мозаике с пьяцца Армерина (Сицилия), однако они служили женской спортивной одеждой, а не для купания[7].