# Портной одежду порет или шьет?

Tags: этимология

Вопрос о происхождении слова ***портной*** уже рассматривался на сайте.

[Происхождение слова "портной"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/39777/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Портной – от пъртный шьвьцо, где пъртъ – одежда, то есть портной – это тот, кто шьет одежду.

Но вот само слово ***пъртъ*** (одежда) может быть связано с глаголами ***пороть/пырять***, сравнить (греч.) piero – колю, режу.

Однако насколько справедливо это утверждение, учитывая, что ***пъртъ*** со значением ***одежда*** отсутствует в славянских языках?

Итак, почему в русском языке одежда называлась ***пъртъ***?

Comment: Согласно словарю П.Я. Черных корень **por-* основной общеславянский корень для всей группы, а, например, **pъr* — абляут к нему (-t- — суффикс).

Comment: Корень, может, и есть, но почему он только в русском языке обозначает одежду?  Одежда - это  ведь то, что сшито, а не то, что разрезано. При этом глагол "шить" имеет и.-е. корень и в русском языке был известен   с 12 века.

Comment: Шьют из  разрезанного (вырезанного). Без ножниц и пончо не сшить.

Answer (score 2):

**Итак, почему в русском языке одежда называлась пъртъ?**

Можно вспомнить другое др.-русск. слово "риза", которое тоже когда-то значило "одежда". Там этимология не совсем понятна, но Фасмер приводит в качестве одной из основных версий происхождение от слова "резать". Вот эта связь больше удивляет. А переход *пороть --> кусок ткани --> одежда* выглядит достаточно последовательным.

Рискну высказать собственную точку зрения, которую не могу подтвердить надёжными источниками.

В древние времена одежда была скорее "облачением" в том смысле, что для её изготовления шитьё имело намного меньшее значение, чем кройка. Ср. *портянки*.

Comment: Кажется, с тех давних времен  мало что изменилось. В швейном деле есть три профессии: швея только шьет, портной шьет и кроит по готовым лекалам и только закройщик  работает с клиентом, выбирает фасон, снимает мерки и делает лекала. Отсюда вывод: пъртъ - это прежде всего скроенная матером одежда и уже потом только сшитая швеёй.

Comment: Вы пробовали когда-нибудь шить платье? По моим детским воспоминаниям с процессом кройки на дому вполне может управиться даже неопытный ребёнок, а аккуратно сшить было сложнее. А теперь представьте себе это в X в. — с тогдашними ножницами, шкурами, лекалами. Учтите, что в случае неудачи при кройке испортится материал, а неудача в шитье — всего лишь потеря времени и, может быть, ниток.